# Is the derivative of the characteristic polynomial equal to the sum of characteristic polynomial of principal submatrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Let $A$ by an $n \times n$ matrix over the complex numbers and let $\phi(A,x) = \det(xI-A)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$.  Let $B_i$ be the principal submatrix of $A$ formed by deleting the $i$-th row and column of $A$. Let $\phi(B_i,x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $B_i$.

Is it always true that the derivative of $\phi(A,x)$ is the sum of $\phi(B_i,x)$ as $i$ ranges across the rows/columns of $A$?

That is, is the following an *identity*?
$$ \frac{d\ \phi(A,x)}{dx} = \sum_i \phi(B_i,x) $$

If not, what is a small counterexample?  (The equation works for all $2 \times 2$ matrices and all adjacency matrices of graphs....)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true.

Proof:

Let
$$
\phi(A,x) =
\det\begin{pmatrix}
  x-a_{1,1} & -a_{1,2} & \cdots & -a_{1,n} \\
  -a_{2,1} & x-a_{2,2} & \cdots & -a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  -a_{m,1} & -a_{m,2} & \cdots & x-a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then, let us expand out this derivative using the multilinearity property of the determinant:
$$
\begin{split}
\phi'(A,x) 
&=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
  1 &0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  -a_{2,1} & x-a_{2,2} & \cdots & -a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  -a_{m,1} & -a_{m,2} & \cdots & x-a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix} \\ 
&\quad +
\det\begin{pmatrix}
  x-a_{1,1} & -a_{1,2} & \cdots & -a_{1,n} \\
  0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  -a_{m,1} & -a_{m,2} & \cdots & x-a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix} \\
&\quad +\dots +
\det\begin{pmatrix}
  x-a_{1,1} & -a_{1,2} & \cdots & -a_{1,n} \\
  -a_{2,1} & x-a_{2,2} & \cdots & -a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \sum _{i=1}^n \phi(B_i,x)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks.  Can you elaborate just a bit on "write the derivative using multilinearity"?  The determinant is $n$-linear, say in the rows.  So how do I track the derivative through that mess?

Comment: there is a property of derivation (from which the product rule is derived) saying that if $M(x_1\dots x_d)$ is multilinear, then $d/dxM(f_1(x)\dots f_d(x)) = M(f_1'(x), f_2(x)\dots f_d(x)) + \dots + M(f_1(x), f_2(x)\dots f_d'(x))$

Comment: $\phi (A,x)$ is not just the matrix $xI-A$, its the det($xI-A$). In the proof, why the determinant is not considered?

Comment: these are determinants at every steps.

Comment: You should have vertical bars for determinants, not matrix parentheses.