# Prove $ {p_{A}(t) = \operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{adj}(tI − A))} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ is a $n \times n $ matrix. If ${p_{A}(t)}$ denotes the *characteristic polynomial of $A$*, I need to prove that 
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace} \DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
{p_{A}(t) = \trace(\adj(tI − A))} 
$$
 I know that ${{\det(A)\,I = \adj(A)\,A}}$. 
So, ${{\det(A-tI)\,I = \adj(A-tI)\,(A-tI)}}$. That is, ${{p_{A}(t)\,I = \adj(A-tI)\,(A-tI)}}$.

I don't know what to do after this and I am not sure whether I need to use some other technique. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The claim in the title is false.

Comment: May I know why it is false? Its a homework problem.

Comment: Each entry of $\operatorname{adj}\left(tI-A\right)$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $n-1$. So is, therefore, the trace (except the degree can be even smaller). But $\det\left(tI-A\right)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: This question hurts my eyes. BURN IT

Comment: @Khosrotash is there a reason you've decided to color everything red?

Comment: First time there was not clear ! but "Omnomnomnom" made it right and clear

Comment: I found that the statement is true if the characteristic polynomial is replaced by its derivative.

Comment: I found it in this link...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978815/is-the-derivative-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-equal-to-the-sum-of-character

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.  In particular, take the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A = 0$.  We have
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace} \DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
p_A(t) = t^2\\
\adj(tI - A) = \adj \left[t I\right] = t I\\
\trace(\adj(tI - A)) = 2t
$$
Check the question statement and fix your post.

Comment: Perhaps there is some sort of derivative missing